# How do I create a function to get value from database

Tags: php, mysql, function

I want to create a function to call a key and value on specific table.

Basically my statement like this

```
$query = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
         '.$key.' 
          FROM users 
          WHERE 
          status="'.$value.'"';
```

Now I want implement in function

```
function counter('what to put here') {
    $query = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
             '.$key.' 
              FROM users 
              WHERE 
              status="'.$value.'"';
if (!($result = @mysql_query($query))) {
die(mysql_error());
}
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS rows'));
return $rows['rows']; // what to return here
}
```

And to call the function

`<?php echo counter('KEY','VALUE'); ?>`

Let me know how to achieve my goal..

Comment: What is your question?
How to name the parameters?

Comment: I can't understand your question well but i am trying to answer - 
`function counter($key,$value)` and you get the result like this: `echo counter('key','value')`.Sorry ,if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes.. How to name the parameters. It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ,I've understand the question , according to poster's comment and I'm posting the answer:
You need to define your function like this:
`function counter($key,$value)`
 and you get the result like this: `echo counter('key','value')`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define your function:

```
function counter($key)
```

This is how you can call it:

```
<?php echo counter('KEY'); ?>
```